# FLUTTER: Displaying problem between IOS and ANDROID

Tags: android, ios, flutter, widget

I did an app and I have a problem, I runned the app on ios and android but one screen is not like I want, all my child in `SizedBox` are not full displayed (only on IOS), I think it is a problem with `Sizedbox` in IOS but I have no Idea how to resolve it.
I try to use other widget but no one works.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('rooms')
              .document(pincode)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              int result =
                  snapshot.data['Votes'][0] - snapshot.data['Votes'][1];
              if (result <= 0)
                perdantID = snapshot.data['Nominés'][1];
              else
                perdantID = snapshot.data['Nominés'][0];
              leperdant = perdantID;
              if (snapshot.data['nb screen'] == 2 && gotdata == 0) {
                gotdata++;
                gonext(context, perdantID);
              }
              return Center(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('rooms')
                      .document(pincode)
                      .collection('users')
                      .document(perdantID)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      var prenomperdant = snapshot.data['prénom'];
                      return Center(
                          child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 30),
                          Text('$prenomperdant',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Text(' $subquestion',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35)),
                          ),
                          StreamBuilder(
                            stream: Firestore.instance
                                .collection('rooms')
                                .document(pincode)
                                .collection('users')
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 140,
                                      child: GridView.count(
                                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                                          children: snapshot.data.documents.map(
                                              (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                            if (document['id'] == nomines[0] ||
                                                document['id'] == nomines[1])
                                              return Container(
                                                child: OvalPic(
                                                    document['photo'],
                                                    document['couleur']),
                                              );
                                            else
                                              return null;
                                          }).toList()
                                            ..removeWhere((el) => el == null)),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                        height: 190,
                                        child: GridView.count(
                                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            ListView.builder(
                                              physics:
                                                  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                              itemCount: nbvotes[0],
                                              reverse: true,
                                              itemBuilder:
                                                  (BuildContext context,
                                                      int index) {
                                                return Align(
                                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.94,
                                                    child: Image(
                                                      image: AssetImage(
                                                          'assets/images/results/green.png'),
                                                    ));
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            ListView.builder(
                                              physics:
                                                  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                              itemCount: nbvotes[1],
                                              reverse: true,
                                              itemBuilder:
                                                  (BuildContext context,
                                                      int index) {
                                                return Align(
                                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                    heightFactor: 0.94,
                                                    child: Image(
                                                      image: AssetImage(
                                                          'assets/images/results/green.png'),
                                                    ));
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )),
                                  ],
                                );
                              } else
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            },
                          ),
                          (perdantID == nameid)
                              ? Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    rbutton(mygreen, 'PASSER AU DEFI', context,
                                        perdantID, ledefi),
                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    Text('OU'),
                                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    rbutton(mypink, 'BOIRE', context, perdantID,
                                        legage),
                                  ],
                                )
                              : SizedBox(height: 1)
                        ],
                      ));
                    } else
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 140),
  child:GridView....,
)
```

instead of

```
SizedBox(
   height: 190,
   child: GridView...
)
```